# In PostgreSQL how do you have multiple check constraints reference the same array of values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Many of the columns in different tables in my database have the constraint `between 1 and 3` (equivalent to `any (array[1,2,3])` since they're all integers). This may need to be changed to allow 4s in the future, so I want to make them all reference a variable.

This database has an singleton info table, so I thought I could maybe add a column to that and reference the sole value in it? I tried the code below but it just said "column privacy_options does not exist"

```sql
alter table info add privacy_options integer array;
update info set privacy_options = array [1,2,3];
alter table system_config add check (default_privacy_shown = any (info(privacy_options)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use subqueries in the `check` constraint. But this should work for you:

```
alter table system_config add check (default_privacy_shown in (1, 2, 3))
```

Also, ensure the coulmn `system_config.default_privacy_shown` exists.

Add it if needed before adding constraint: `alter table system_config add default_privacy_shown integer`.

Comment: That's what I already have. It *works* but it causes the problem of having the exact same constraint on at least 25 columns across 4 tables that will need to be modified at some point all individually, which causes a very high risk of one being forgotten, so I'd hoped I could link them together somehow.

Comment: You can probably use [domain constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html) for this purpose.

Comment: Domain would be a great solution, but I'm pretty sure it won't let you alter the constraint on it. You can remove an existing constraint on a domain that is in use, but not (AFAIK) apply a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You may make a very simple helper function:

```sql
create or replace function privacy_helper(v integer) returns boolean
immutable language sql as
$$
  select v in (1,2,3);
$$;
```

and then 40+ times

```sql
alter table the_table add check (privacy_helper(the_column));
```

Any change of the target set will be done only once, in the function.

Here is the function using `info` table:

```sql
create or replace function privacy_helper(v integer) returns boolean
stable language sql as
$$
  select v = any((select privacy_options from info));
$$;
```